# Does erasing elements from a vector also erase all the member vectors present in the elements?

Tags: c++, memory, stdvector

I am conditionally erasing elements from a vector instance (`AVector`) of objects (`AnObject`s) using `erase` and `remove_if`.

In my scenario, `AnObject` has an `Anothervector` (of `Anotherobject`s) as one of its member variables. I want to erase any AnObject that have `Anothervector` size as 0.
Note: `BVector` is another vector of `AnObject`s. `condition_1` is a predicate.

```
// Copy elements from BVector to AVector based on a condition
    for (int i = 0; i < BVector.size(); i++)
            {
                AnObject temp;
                AVector.push_back(temp);
                std::copy_if(BVector.at(i).getVector().begin(), BVector.at(i).getVector().end(), back_inserter(AVector.at(i).getVector()), condition_1);
            }
// Trim the AVector by removing AnObjects with Anothervector of size 0
auto const cond_trim = [](AnObject& anobj)
{
    // std::cout << "Size is " << anobj.getVector().size();
    return anobj.getVector().size() == 0;
};

std::vector<Anotherobject>& AnObject::getVector()
{
    return Anothervector;
}

auto iter = std::remove_if(AVector.begin(), AVector.end(), cond_trim);
AVector.erase(iter, AVector.end());
```

**UPDATE**
Bug found - Erasing an object (`AnObject`) in the `AVector` is not erasing the member vector (`Anothervector`).

Comment: You are using the end iterator of a different vector.

Comment: @Galik, Sorry for that typo. I fixed it.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @NathanOliver, I made up the example from my code. The code is around 1000 lines so far. I tried to convey all the aspects as much as possible. I want to know what could be the causes of such a bug (theoretical reasons). Then I can fix the bug in my code.

Comment: You should cut'n'paste your real code into the question. Trim it down to as few lines as possible to reproduce the bug. We can't debug your real code from a *rough copy* of the parts you think might be relevant.

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me (after filling in the missing pieces)

Comment: @Galik, I added more code which could reproduce the bug.

Comment: `AnObject temp = AnObject();` Don't do this. Just write `AnObject temp;`

Comment: Don't add "more code"; present your [MCVE], as you were already instructed to do.

Answer (score 1):

`cond_trim` should accept an element of a collection, not a collection itself, i.e. an object of type `AnObject`, not `Avector`.

Comment: This maybe a typo in your example, cause it should not even compile (unless AVector inherits from AnObject).